# Neo4J - Neogma - TypeError: Cannot read property 'queryRunner' of undefined

Tags: node.js, neo4j

Good morning,

I am using neogma to simplify the use of Neo4J. When I separate, the DB connection initialization, the models and API controllers in separate files, it throws the following error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'queryRunner' of undefined"
at Object.ModelFactory (/Users/name/Desktop/greenform-backend/node_modules/neogma/src/ModelOps/ModelOps.ts:382:32)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/name/Desktop/greenform-backend/src/database/models/Movies.ts:17:23)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
at Module.m._compile (/Users/name/Desktop/greenform-backend/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1056:23)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/name/Desktop/greenform-backend/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1059:12)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1140:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
```

The DB connection is set in the server.ts file:

```
export const neogma = new Neogma(
{
    url: db.db_url,
    username: db.db_user,
    password: db.db_pw,
},
{
    logger: console.log,
    encrypted: false,
},
```

);

The model schema is set in a separate file:

```
export const Movies = ModelFactory<MoviesPropertiesI, MoviesRelatedNodesI>(
{
    label: 'Movie',
    primaryKeyField: 'name',
    schema: {
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            minLength: 1,
            required: true,
        },
        year: {
            type: 'number',
            minimum: 1900,
            required: true,
        },
    },
},
neogma,);
```

And the controller is in a separate file:

```
import express from 'express';
import { Users, UsersPropertiesI } from '../../database/models/Users';

const router = express.Router();

const populateData = async (): Promise<void> => {
const user = await Users.build({
    name: 'Barry',
    age: 36,
});

console.log(user.name);

await user.save({
    validate: true,
    session: null,
});
};

router.post('/db', (req, res) => populateData()
.then(() => {
    res.json({ message: "success" })
})
.catch(
    (err)=> console.log(err))
)

export default router;
```

When put the controller and the DB init in one file it works perfectly fine. But in separate files an error is thrown.

Do you know how to fix that issue?

Comment: If you found the solution, mark your solution as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

Just got a hint from: https://github.com/themetalfleece/neogma/issues/7

To export the file and make use of the neogma object, it needs to be initialized before importing other database-related dependencies.